# When is a Windows folder available to Java's `File#list`?

Tags: java, windows, filesystems

I have some Java code that does this (on a Windows 10 laptop with Windows Defender on):

- unzip a .zip file into a folder (using a zip stream)
- immediately list the folder's contents (using `File#list`)

There are ten files in the zip, from 100kB to 40MB. Normally only the first two files are listed -- the other 8 are silently lost. I know they actually make it to the directory because I can see them when I navigate to the directory myself.

I know there are better ways to implement this code, but I'm curious: is this expected? Is "write file into folder" and "file is listed when you list folder contents" not atomic on Windows? Is it a quirk of the underlying file system? Does Windows Defender make the file invisible for some period of time after it's written?

Comment: No, this behaviour is unexpected. Share your code an we will try to help you

Comment: It's literally just that. Take a zip file, unzip it into a directory, call new File(directoryName).list() on it. I can't share the exact code because it's for work, but there's nothing fancy going on.

Comment: Of course there is something fancy going on - thousands of developers are unzipping files with Java without this problem. What file names are in the archive? Are they variations of each other with different capitalizations? In that case, since Windows file systems are case insensitive, files extracted later will overwrite files extracted earlier

Comment: Edited the text to note: "I know they actually make it to the directory because I can see them when I navigate to the directory myself."

There's no overwriting. It's possible (?) some security software on the laptop is scanning the files (they're jars) and they're briefly not visible as a result. This code runs just fine on Linux and Macs.

Comment: are you trying to list it in a different thread?

Comment: Same thread. It's happening strictly later.

Comment: We can't keep guessing. You need to post your code to ask a question about the operation of your code. If you can't post your code, then StackOverflow is not the right site for your question.

Comment: It's not a question about the code -- the code is correct. It's a question about what aspect of the environment -- security software, file system, etc. might cause this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I am not facing the issue you mentioned and my code is able to list all the files correctly:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class ZipTest {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    private static String INPUT_LOCATION = "C:/temp/zip/test.zip";
    private static String OUTPUT_LOCATION = "C:/temp/unzip";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        unzip(INPUT_LOCATION, OUTPUT_LOCATION);
        for (String s : new File(OUTPUT_LOCATION).list()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException {
        File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
        if (!destDir.exists()) {
            destDir.mkdir();
        }
        ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
        ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();

        while (entry != null) {
            String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
            } else {
                File dir = new File(filePath);
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            zipIn.closeEntry();
            entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        }
        zipIn.close();
    }

    private static void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath) throws IOException {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
        }
        bos.close();
    }
}
```